# Подключение к БД (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

**Правильно ли я подключаюсь к БД?**

При подключение выходит ошибка на `adapter.Fill(table);`

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
    private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Start();
    }

    public static string Datasource = "localhost";
    public static string Port = "3306";
    public static string InitialCatalog = "user";
    public static string Username = "user";
    public static string Password = "pass";

    //MySql
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + Datasource + ";port=" + Port + ";Initial Catalog='" + InitialCatalog + "';username=" + Username + ";password=" + Password);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    public void MySqlConnect()
    {
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" + textBoxUsername.Text + "' AND `password` = '" + textBoxPassword.Text + "'", connection);
        adapter.Fill(table); //PROBLEM

        if (table.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            panel1.Height = 0;
            labelMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            labelMessage.Text = "Username Or Password Are Invalid";
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Height = 0;
            labelMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            labelMessage.Text = "Login Successfully";
            timer1.Start();
        }

        table.Clear();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Height != 100)
        {
            panel1.Height = panel1.Height + 5;
            if (panel1.Height == 100)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Height != 0)
        {
            panel1.Height = panel1.Height - 5;
            if (panel1.Height == 0)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkBoxShowPass_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBoxShowPass.Checked)
        {
            textBoxPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        }
    }
...
```

**Текст ошибки**

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Сообщение = Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  Источник = MySql.Data
  Внутреннее исключение 1:
MySqlException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки

Comment: Без информации об ошибки можно только гадать, что Вы не сделали -похоже, что  нет connection.open()

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, если не ошибаюсь, то адаптер сам рулит соединением и сам открывает/закрывает его.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ,  я то же сейчас точно не помню, нужен ли перед Fill() явное открытие базы. Все было бы очень просто, если бы автор вопроса дал бы полную информацию

Comment: UPD: Добавил код ошибки. @АлександрМуксимов Это весь код который работает с БД, не считая вызова  "MySqlConnect();"

Comment: ох уж эти подключения к БД с гуя... Как страшный сон.

Comment: @Sleeeper добро пожаловать в мой мир)

Comment: Убрал минус, утром, если будет время посмотрю, но ничего не обещаю

Comment: Та учетка под которой ты конектишься имеет права на базу?

Comment: Попробуй через IDE для работы с СУБД зайти в базу под этими данными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке у этой учетки отсутствуют права на доступ к данной БД.

Попробуйте через IDE подключиться к БД. Я уверен, что вы получите такую же ошибку => ваш код не причем и нужно копать в сторону прав.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая, 100%-но рабочая

```
@"user=***;password=***;server=localhost;database=dbname;port=3306;"
```